# How to merge cells with equal values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this Table where I need to merge cells with same value for a column Week. 
Below is the Table I am getting as an output right now:

```
Week    Project     OS      TotalTests  #cycle of run 
1        P1        ABC     0                 0
1        P2       XYZ     4799               1
```

I want the output to be like ( 1 should be placed at the center of a cell) :

```
  Week  Project     OS      TotalTests  #cycle of run 
    1        P1        ABC     0                 0
             P2       XYZ     4799               1
```

Here is the code:

```
function BindTable(startWW, endWW, selPhaseNumber, selctedYear) {
        var url = webApiUrl + .....

        $('#GraphTable > tbody > tr ').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { .... },
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {


                    var tr;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].WW + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Project + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].OS + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].TotalTests + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CycleRun + "</td>");

                        $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<th colspan='10' style='text-align:center'>No Data to display</th>");

                    $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help ?

Comment: Keep the track of the previous `data[i].WW` outside your `for`, update it with each iteration, and only put text inside the first `<td>` if the current and previous values are different.

Comment: hint: build the table from the end to the beginning, so you know the value for the `rowspan` attribute :)

Comment: PS: `colspan="10"` but in the code block above you're only appending 5 td-elements... That doesn't match!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine cells with the `rowspan` attribute. The Problem: If you loop through the data from the beginning, you don't know the right value for the rowspan-attribute, because ithas to be placed in the first td-element!

Solution: Loop through it from the end to the beginning:

```
function success(data) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var oldValue = data[data.length-1].WW,
        c=1;
    for (var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let $tr = $('<tr/>');
      if(i==0 || oldValue != data[i-1].WW) {
        $tr.append("<td rowspan=\""+c+"\">" + data[i].WW + "</td>");
        c = 1;
        if(i>0) oldValue = data[i-1].WW;
      } else {
        c++;
      }
      $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Project + "</td>");
      $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].OS + "</td>");
      $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].TotalTests + "</td>");
      $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CycleRun + "</td>");
      $('#GraphTable').prepend($tr);
    }
  } else {
    let $tr = $('<tr/>');
    $tr.append("<th colspan='5' style='text-align:center'>No Data to display</th>");
    $('#GraphTable').append($tr);
  }
}
```

*working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hafuaL6/)*

EDIT: *working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/j7usutbj/) with head-line*

changed the loop order and naming convention.

Comment: I tried this but if I add WW = 2 in db and try again. Its not working. Its again displaying like  1  1  2 (for column Weak)

Comment: Created a fiddle by myself and tested the code. Yes there was an issue. Now it's working fine.

Comment: wow too fast. I was about to update the output images. Thanks a lot its working:)

Answer (score 0):

If you track the last DataWW you could print it or not. You only need to print when last DataWW is different from current DataWW. You can adjust your for loop like this:

```
var tr;
var lastDataWW = null
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  if (lastDataWW != data[i].WW) {
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].WW + "</td>");
  else {
    tr.append("<td> </td>");
  }
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Project + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].OS + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].TotalTests + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CycleRun + "</td>");
  $('#GraphTable').append(tr);

  lastDataWW = data[i].WW
}
```

And as Santi said below the comments, you could center the first column if you add this css in your style sheet.

```
/* CSS */
#GraphTable tr td:first-child { 
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: the questioner wants the `data[i].WW` in the center of the combined column

Comment: @marquesm91 Thanks for the answer. Its working. As Joshua said I want the <data[i].WW> to be centered. I can figure this out. :)

Comment: @shreyPav Put this in your css: `#GraphTable tr td:first-child { text-align: center; }`, or if you want them *all* to be centered, just remove the `:first-child` portion.

Comment: No you missunderstood the questioner: He wants to center it within the cell verticaly, not horizontal. And this is not working with your code. You have to use rowspan, but you cannot or have to update the td elements at the end, and count the amount of equal cell content when you loop through it the first time

Comment: @Santi The code you gave makes the value centered in its cell. I wanted all the equal cells to be merged and value displayed in its center. My bad coz in my expected output its not clear. :)

Comment: @JoshuaK exactly :)